Keycloak running in context of an Azure Container Instance - Exception: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
I have a question related to Keycloak and would like to thank you in advance for any advice.
I deployed Keycloak (version 20.0.5) in the context of an Azure Container Instance (CPU: 1, Memory 1,5 GB), and its related database is a SQL database (Pricing tier: Standard S0: 10 DTUs) which is also deployed on Azure.
Most of the time, the connection between Keycloak and the SQL database works, but regularly, I observe the following logs:
2024-06-26 10:20:36,971 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Timer-0) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
2024-06-26 10:20:36,971 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (Timer-0) Acquisition timeout while waiting for new connection
2024-06-26 10:20:36,972 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.scheduled.ScheduledTaskRunner] (Timer-0) Failed to run scheduled task ClearExpiredUserSessions: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection

That exception occurs every 30 minutes, sometimes just every hour. This leads to a failed connection for ~2 minutes. After that, everything is fine.
My question is whether you have any advice, instruction, or whatever could help me to determine what this connection problen causes:
•   Am I using the wrong pricing tier combination (ACI: SKU == Standard, SQL == Standard), I already upgraded the SQL from Basic to Standard
•   Could it be a problem due to the Pool Size? (I didn’t configure that, I'm using the default one)
•   Could it be that there are too many connections/sessions request to the SQL? Although I should not exceed the limits (see below)
•   Is there anything, which might happen inside the Keycloak Container due to a configuration mistake?
•   Is maybe an Azure Container Instance not ideal for running Keycloak? Can some of those connection problems occur when maybe the Container is moved to a different cluster?

Thank you!

Seems like a resource crunch issue. Can you update your ACI deployment to allocate more CPU and memory and give it a try?

@Arko ah, interesting - I would have thought that would be enough. Yes, I can try that - I'll give you an update! Thx for the hint!

@Arko I adapted the ACI and set the cpu to 4 cores and the memory to 8GB. So far the error didn't pop up - but I checked the logs of the previous instance, there it took almost 24 hours to get this error. So, I'll observe it now unitl tomorrow and I'll give you another update by latest tomorrow early afternoon. thx!

The exception occured again...with an Azure Container Instance with 4 CPU cores and 8GB memory.... :(
